# Show current active cell in another

Tags: excel-formula

How can I show the current active cell in say A1 & have A1 automatically update as I move around the sheet? Taking it a stage further, how can I show the active sheet in say A2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this through formulas alone but through VBA you could do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("A1") = Target.Address
End Sub
```

With your point on Sheet Name, you'd have to use:`ActiveSheet.Name`but then you'd never be able to see it on the sheet where you're showing it...

Comment: Thanks Tim.

Am aware of the VBA solution but really I'm looking for it to change automatically. Hence my desire to use a formula. I've tried using a function (instead of a sub) A1=function("A1:Z200") but this only gets invoked when I change a cell it depends on & not movement to a new cell.

Take your point about not being able to see the sheet name in A2 but I'm looking to eventually use the values of A1 & A2. I don't need to see them.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't envisage a way you can do the equivalent of selection without VBA. I guess depending on how you end up using A1 and A2 (as you allude to) you could work something out at the point of that calculation, good luck.

Comment: Tim. Apologies. Found & successfully used http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-event-ms-excel-cell-selected-40335.html where the worksheet event usage is described.